# When do I pronounce “i” in “sci-”?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation

From [orbilat](http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Italian/Grammar/Italian-Pronunciation_and_Spelling.html):

> the i is not pronounced in the combinations ci, gi, and sci when they
>   are followed by a, o or u, unless the accent falls on the i

But what is the role in words like *sciare* [ʃiˈaːre]?

Comment: You are perfectly right. This just proves that this “orbilat” thing isn't reliable. Adding it to “[non-resources](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/a-list-of-non-resources)”, thanks!

Comment: Someone should really work on the Italian wikibook to make it a reasonable resource (not that I'm volunteering, but someone should).

Comment: According to [this comment to Aula di Lingue Zanichelli](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2013/10/24/laccento-in-italiano/#comment-16191) the "i" after "sc" is pronounced only in the noun "scia", in the forms of the verb "sciare" and in the derivatives of "sci" (for instance, "sciata").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Main law about exceptions** (MLAE)

> *Every rule has its exceptions, including the main law about exceptions*

You'll find several applications of the MLAE when dealing with grammar or orthography.

The trigraph *sci* is normally used for denoting the /ʃ/ phoneme in front of *a*, *o* or *u* (like for *ci* and *gi*). For etymological reasons, *sciare* has two syllables (sci-are). The [Treccani dictionary](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sciare2/) makes this apparent by writing the entry as “scïare”, where the dieresis denotes a hiatus.

There's no hard and fast rule: after all, exceptions are cases that cannot be linked together in a rule or subrule.

However, this case is easy: I'm not aware of other words that share the same exception to the main *sci* rule. As far as I know, *sciare* and the other words derived from *sci* (English *ski*) are the only ones where one should consider the spelling as “(sc)iare” unlike in “(sci)arpa” (the parentheses denote a digraph or trigraph, for clarity).

There is also *scia* (English *wake*), where the *i* is tonic, so *sci* cannot be considered a trigraph.

See [this forum](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2013/10/24/laccento-in-italiano/#comment-16191) (thanks to Charo for the pointer).

It's not rare, but not frequent either, to hear the word *sciare* pronounced as /'ʃare/ for analogy with all other similar words.

There are also exceptions in the other direction: an *i* might follow *sc* and not be pronounced at all:

> scienza coscienza usciere

keep their *i* for etymological reasons, but there's no /i/ or /j/ sound in the pronunciation.

Comment: According to [this comment to Aula di Lingue Zanichelli](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2013/10/24/laccento-in-italiano/#comment-16191) the "i" after "sc" is pronounced only in the noun "scia", in the forms of the verb "sciare" and in the derivatives of "sci" (for instance, "sciata").

Comment: @Charo In *scia* there is a tonic *i*. Thanks, I'll update.

Comment: There are some more possible exceptions: for *sciente* (and *scientemente*) the pronunciation with an “i” is prescribed ([Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sciente/)) or admitted (Zingarelli, [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sciente)). (And one *could* argue about a [stʃiabat:ˈare] pronunciation for *sciabattare*...)

Comment: @DaG I didn't even think to *scientemente*: I'm surprised about what Treccani imposes.

Answer (score -2):

In Italian there is this rule:
sc + vowel is pronounced like the English "SH", IPA: ʃ,
sc + consonant is pronounced like the English "SK", just like in the English "ski".

So in the word "sciare" [ʃiˈaːre] I have to put an "i" before the "a" in order to pronounce "SH", IPA: ʃ .

Comment: I think you are missing that there is a substantial difference between the pronunciation of *sciare* (/ʃiˈaːre/) and *sciarpa* (/'ʃaːrpa/) and the OP would like to know the reason for it.

Comment: And the rule, as stated, is wrong.